# SparkThrift server on Different port

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run Spark thrift server on different port say 12000.  I referred Spark sql document  and other urls but sill not able to run Spark thrift server on different port.It can't run on port 10000 as that is being used by Hive.
I also referred https://github.com/abhibasu/sparksql/wiki/SparkSQL-Configuration-in-CDH-5.3  and made the changes.
Tried to start Spark thrift  from Spark_home/sbin> export HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT=12000
Spark_home/sbin> ./start-thriftserver.sh

Log file shows below error.
ERROR thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error:
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12000.

Environment: CDH5.3.3, SPark 1.2.0, Hive 0.13.1
Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
./start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=9999
```

If you are running on Yarn:

```
./start-thriftserver.sh --master yarn --conf spark.ui.port=4049 --executor-memory 500M --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 1024M --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=9999
```

you can provide hive conf as property key value using --hiveconf